# How do you call the opposite of an ion?

Tags: terminology

According to IUPAC, an ion is defined as:

> An atomic or molecular particle having a net electric charge. ([source](https://doi.org/10.1351/goldbook.I03158))

But how do you call an atomic or molecular particle that does not have a net electric charge? Is there a noun or an adjective that one can use to refer to the opposite of an ion?

Comment: _"Atom"_ or _"molecule"_ sounds good enough for me. If you want an umbrella term, go with _"uncharged particle"_. I don't think there is a single word for that.

Comment: I checked: according to IUPAC, an "atom" consists of *Z* protons and *Z* electrons ([source](https://doi.org/10.1351/goldbook.A00493)). That is, by definition, an "atom" has a net electric charge of zero. I did not expect this, because using this definition, ions do not qualify to be called atoms. That doesn't seem to reflect the common usage of these terms.

Comment: In my field, one could call it a neutral.

Comment: The common usage of many terms is just wrong.

Comment: @Ivan Well, the idea behind having definitions is to reduce ambiguity, but obviously in this case the definition actually introduces ambiguity itself, because IUPAC's idea of an atom is very different from how the word is actually used. Therefore I think talking about "atoms" would be misleading. I appreciate the other suggestions though.

Comment: @FeliGoldstein Atom and molecule definitely neutral. "Common usage" depends on context. My adviser, for one, insisted that terms be correctly used, so the common usage was the correct usage. For example, you abstract a hydrogen atom in a radical reaction but deprotonate a hydrogen ion.

Comment: @FeliGoldstein What ambiguity are you talking about? How else is the word 'atom' actually used?

Comment: atom is occasionally used when the term nuclei would be more appropriate.

Comment: When or where an ion is called atom? Never saw/eared that.